# Programmatically created file doesn't always inherit the permissions of the parent folder

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-server-2008

(This may be better suited to ServerFault - if so please migrate it!)

We recently upgraded servers from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008.  We have now been getting reports that certain PDF files which are dynamically generated are giving "access is denied" messages.  I've verified that the folder has "Full Control" to the user group that is being utilized, yet it seems that intermittently files are created without inheriting the parent permissions.

For instance, the parent folder is called Paperwork.  The "Users" group is set up to have full control to all files and subfolders within that directory.  This works 95% of the time.  Once in a while, though, a file will be created and when I view the security permission *for that file*, the "Users" group does **not** have Full Control access.

Is there something programmatic that needs to be changed for Windows Server 2008, or is this a configuration issue on the server itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this

[image]

try this :

```
 private DirectorySecurity GetDirectorySecurity(string owner)
    {
        const string LOG_SOURCE = "GetDirectorySecurity";
        DirectorySecurity ds = new DirectorySecurity();

        System.Security.Principal.NTAccount ownerAccount =
            new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(owner);

        ds.SetOwner(ownerAccount);

        ds.AddAccessRule(
            new FileSystemAccessRule(owner,
            FileSystemRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, 
            PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
            AccessControlType.Allow));

        //AdminUsers is a List<string> that contains a list from configuration
        //  That represents the admins who should be allowed
        foreach (string adminUser in AdminUsers)
        {
            ds.AddAccessRule(
                new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUser,
                FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
                AccessControlType.Allow));
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

ref : 
[File permissions do not inherit directory permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532014/file-permissions-do-not-inherit-directory-permissions)

Comment: Will that propagate to newly created objects that aren't currently in the directory?  I mean for all future files created.