# create and modify folders from code behind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .net

I am trying to give the ability of creating image galleries for each ASP.Net user, where:

All folders are under a specific sub folder ~\uploads

Each gallery will have a specific folder named by the GalleryID.

Each folder should be modifiable by the admin or the user who created it only.

In code behind i used:

```
        Dim GPath As String = _
        System.IO.Path.Combine("~\Uploads\", GetGalleryID()))
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(GPath)
```

This code throws:

> Access to the path '~\Uploads\22' is denied.

a suggested solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713377/how-do-you-create-folders-and-specify-access-permissions-on-them-at-the-same-tim) says :

*Grant permission to create directories and files (read/write/modify/...) to the worker process group (sysname\iis_wpg) to the parent directory.*

I am using IIS 7.5 under Windows server 2003 and i couldn't find the iis_wpg?
I've applied the solution on IIS_IUSERS but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `~\Uploads\` is a url. You need to map that into a physical path on server file system. Use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for this

```
Dim GFolder As String = Server.MapPath("~\Uploads\")
Dim GPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(GFolder, GetGalleryID()))
```

Comment: Correct! I don't know how i missed that, iis_wpg confused me. Thanks.